Determine the number of triplets $(A,B,C)$ of non-degenerate intervals that simultaneously fulfill some conditions:
the problem
Determine the number of triplets $(A,B,C)$ of non-degenerate intervals that simultaneously fulfill the conditions:

one is closed, one open and one semi-open
$A\subset (B \cap C)$
$B\cup C=R$
$card(B \cap N)=8$
$card(C\cap (Z-N))=2$
the finite ends of the intervals are integers

my idea
By 3 we get to know that B and C are the open and the semiopen intervals because they must contain $(-\infty$ and $\infty$
By 4 we get to know that B is the one that contains $- \infty$ and by 5 we get to know that C is  the one that contains $\infty$
Also by 4 we get to know that B have as the second number $8)$ or $7]$ and by 5 we realise that C have as the second number $-3)$ or $-2]$
Now we take 2 cases:

if B is open and C is semiopen then $B=(-\infty, 8)$ and $C=[-2,\infty)$

then $B\cap C=[-2,8)$ and A must be closed and by (6) we get that A can take $11*10:2=55$ values

if B is semi-open and C is open then $B=(-\infty, 7]$ and $C=(-3,\infty)$

then $B\cap C=(-3,7]$ and A must be closed and by 6 we get that A can take $11*10:2=55$ values
The number of triplets $(A,B,C)$ of non-degenerate intervals that simultaneously fulfill the conditions is $55*2=110$
Im not sure on the part where I said  that B have as the second number $8)$ or $7]$ and by 5 we realise that C have as the second number $-3)$ or $-2]$, because I don't know if I could also count 0 in the cardinal. Also I'm not sure if my rationament is correct. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Does $\mathbb N$ contain $0$ in this problem?

If $\mathbb N$ contains $0$ (only in this case “B have as the second number 8) or 7], C have as the second number −3) or −2]” is true), then $[-2,8)$ and $(-3,7]$ have $10$ integers each. So the answer would be $2\cdot\frac{10\cdot9}2=90$.

@Aig Oooo...i see that i calculated the number of values wrong. And also ,,Does N
contain 0
in this problem?" this is also my question put in the post....It doesn't specify so I guess N contain 0...What do you think about it?

I don’t know if $\mathbb N$ contains $0$ here, it could easily be either way. If this is a problem from the book, then check the preface of the book to see. If a teacher gave you this problem, then ask them to clarify. I guess, usually $0$ does not count as a natural number in Romania.
